# Mystery bug photographed in Brasil

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

Shot in Brasil.  Anybody know what it is called!!?

Comment: Hazarding a guess here: you've got a true bug that's about to take flight. Given that event, I don't think the evidence at hand is enough to go deeper.

Answer (score 4):

From this photo (beautiful shot, btw!) you can see that it must be a true bug - admittedly, the diagnostic characteristics are hard to spot, but I will try to walk you there.

Most apparently, we see an insect (six legs) with [sucking mouthparts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insect_mouthparts#Piercing_and_sucking_insects). Admittedly, the rostrum is hidden behind the bucculae (for an explanation of the bucculae compare this graphics [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Heteroptera_morphology-v.svg) and [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Heteroptera_morphology-l.svg)).
But besides the bucculae, the *absence* of chewing/biting mouthparts is apparent.
We further see long, segmented antenna, sclerotized forewings, a considerable pronotum and a dorso-ventrally flattened abdomen.
From the entirety of these characteristics, we can conclude it must be a [true bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroptera).

[image: Pentatomomorphan true bug]

True bugs are divided into [seven infraorders](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systematik_der_Wanzen), of which three are (semi)aquatic (Gerromorpha, Leptopodomorpha and Nepomorpha), one comprises only miniature species (Dipsocoromorpha) and one comprises only ground-dwelling, cryptic species (Enicocephalomorpha).
The two remaing infraorders are ideally distinguished by microscopic dissection (compare the detailed Wikipedia articles in German for [Cimicomorpha](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cimicomorpha) and [Pentatomomorpha](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatomomorpha)), but from experience, I think it must be a Pentatomomorpha.

With this knowledge, I run an [inverse Google search](https://lens.google.com/search?ep=gisbubu&hl=en&re=df&vpw=1531&vph=869&p=AUM6UZDivpQqwDHipyT39d58tP1gZp51tm9T2RPkeeFyHCXlWEbH0YU0x6bxunknnVAjDIvlf5Ukh4kS_MEwSJ3PvSauypIVLzdC5cVs0BSMuN8UMCRL9XEKRmB3wEnNTFEGZn7fiiNBSBQn2JW54LjQkbAcR2Ki7xYUYxTEbNmk5EbnSquyXX2GlfZ5sY0W9bxx3B_RDDQXNo60gw%3D%3D#lns=W251bGwsbnVsbCxudWxsLG51bGwsbnVsbCxudWxsLG51bGwsIkVrY0tKRFU0WmpRM05XUTVMVGxoTmpVdE5EbGlNUzA1WVRFNExUWmlabU5rTnpVNU9XSTRNUklmT0hwV2VrbDVXbUoyVVZsWVRVbG5SM0JuU1V4dVVETnZWV3MzZVc1U1p3PT0iXQ==) on the photo - ***caution**: this is **not** best practice in species identification* - what to my surprise already correctly identified the specimen as a true bug.
Among the images (whereof several were arbitrary red-colored insects) was an image of [*Sphictyrtus chrysis* on iNaturalist](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/607625-Sphictyrtus-chrysis), that looks very similar to the photographed specimen. Besides the habitus, this would be the:

- black forewings
- black pronotum with red margins
- black antenna with a club-shaped last segment
- black legs
- red head with black eyes
- dorsal segments red with black margins with a thin, white line

According to [GBIF](https://www.gbif.org/species/4388775), *S. chrysis* seems to be common in eastern South America, including Brazil.
There is the possibility that similar species (maybe even from the same genus *Sphictyrtus*) exist in Brazil, but this is the best I could infer from this photo as someone unfamiliar with the South American true bug fauna.